# Getting no Data from Yahoo-Finance

Tags: python

I have the following Problem. I'm new in programming and I'm currently trying to import financial data from yahoo to make some analysis. But for some reason Python can't fetch the data for the first ticker. Here is the function where the problem came up(The function save_sp500_tickers() works fine):

```py
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500 = False):

    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open("sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
                tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists("stock_dfs"):
        os.makedirs("stock_dfs")

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists("stock_df/{}.csv".format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
            df.to_csv("stock_df/{}.csv".format(ticker))
        else:
            print("Already have{}".format(ticker))


    get_data_from_yahoo()
```

```
Aaron's Inc.   

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    156             j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 157             data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    158         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'HistoricalPriceStore'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-70d65e54c473> in <module>
----> 1 get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False)

<ipython-input-45-9c120fc94d41> in get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500)
     15         print(ticker)
     16         if not os.path.exists("stock_df/{}.csv".format(ticker)):
---> 17             df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
     18             df.to_csv("stock_df/{}.csv".format(ticker))
     19         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    385             retry_count=retry_count,
    386             pause=pause,
--> 387             session=session,
    388         ).read()
    389 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py in read(self)
    249         # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    250         if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 251             df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    252         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    253         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    158         except KeyError:
    159             msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"
--> 160             raise RemoteDataError(msg.format(symbol, self.__class__.__name__))
    161 
    162         # price data

RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol Aaron's Inc.
 using YahooDailyReader
```

It would be verry nice if somebody could explain me why this RemoteDataError come up

Thank's and greetings from Germany

Comment: The errors seems to be in another part of the code, which you haven't shared with us...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].